# Generate keypair for EVP based on engine

Tags: openssl, rsa

Up until now I did the following:

```
    rsa=RSA_generate_key(2048,RSA_F4,NULL,NULL);
    if (rsa == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not generate keypair \r\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }     
    if ((pk=EVP_PKEY_new()) == NULL){ 
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not instantiate new evp key storage\r\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }    

    if (!EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA(pk,rsa)){
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not assign keypair to evp key storage\r\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
```

However, now I want to be able to use my custom openssl engine. Can you tell me how this is done ?

Answer (score 3):

You have to load the engine first. I think the best way is loading it dynamically (otherwise you would be required to compile it together with openssl):

```
ENGINE_load_dynamic();
ENGINE *your_engine = ENGINE_by_id("dynamic");

...

if (!ENGINE_ctrl_cmd_string(your_engine, "SO_PATH", "path to your engine here (*.so or *.dll), 0))
{
    // your error handler   
}
if (!ENGINE_ctrl_cmd_string(your_engine, "LIST_ADD", "1", 0))
{
 // your error handler  
}
if (!ENGINE_ctrl_cmd_string(your_engine, "LOAD", NULL, 0))
{
    // your error handler       
}
if (!ENGINE_init(your_engine))
{   
    // your error handler   
}

// You can load your private keys this way:
if (!(pk = ENGINE_load_private_key(your_engine, "probably your password...", NULL, NULL))) 
{

}

// You need to tell OpenSSL that you want to use your Engine, for RSA stuff, for example you may do like this
ENGINE_set_default_RSA(your_engine);

...
```

To generate Keys, however, I don't know if it is possible by using only OpenSSL native interface. For my project I've created a custom command. So, in the ENGINE_CMD_DEFN inside the engine, I've added the following:

```
static const ENGINE_CMD_DEFN md_defns[] = {
    ...    
    {CMD_GEN_KEYPAIR, "CMD_GEN_KEYPAIR", "Used to generate a key pair", ENGINE_CMD_FLAG_STRING}
    ...
};
```

You, then, have to handle this command inside your overloaded ctrl_function (the one you've setted using `ENGINE_set_ctrl_function(...)`. You probably already have a switch case there, so just add another case.

To call this command from your application, use `ENGINE_ctrl_cmd("CMD_GEN_KEYPAIR", 1, (void *)(&adittionalInfo));`, putting in adittionalInfo enough information for you to generate your key. In my case, I've created a hook like C struct that both my application and my engine know about it, so that my engine can blindly cast it to the correct type.

After generating your key, load it with `ENGINE_load_private_key`.

I don't know if this is the "best" way, but was suitable for my needs.